# Email Attachments are storing in Tomcat home directory

Tags: email, tomcat, jakarta-mail

We send attachments in the emails using Java mail.

But the attachments are keep storing in Tomcat home directory. We have to delete every day to avoid memory issues. Do we have any option to avoid this

Comment: Maybe you can schedule a cronjob to clean the files old than 3 days on that folder every day

Answer (score 0):

There's no option in JavaMail to delete attachments after sending them.  But your code must be creating the attachments, so it should be your code that's deleting them after sending them.